# Compare list to range and return the column heading(s) if all values of list are present in cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to create a table that will show when selected people from a band are available at the same time.

There are multiple bands and some people are listed in more than one band.

I've gotten as far as getting all of the people that are available listed in the appropriate cells, but taking that list and comparing it to the band lists is giving me fits.

This is what I have at this point (I've tried several iterations of `REGEXMATCH()` without luck), but it's still showing some bands available that it shouldn't.

```excel
=ARRAYFORMULA(
ArrayFormula(
  IF(REGEXMATCH(
    {IF(Dalene!B2:CH13="",Dalene!A1&"|",)&
    IF(Rachel!B2:CH13="",Rachel!A1&"|",)&
    IF(Phillip!B2:CH13="",Phillip!A1&"|",)&
    IF(Jay!B2:CH13="",Jay!A1&"|",)&
    IF(Jameson!B2:CH13="",Jameson!A1&"|",)&
    IF('Scott E'!B2:CH13="",'Scott E'!A1&"|",)&
    IF(Chuck!B2:CH13="",Chuck!A1&"|",)&
    IF(Jennifer!B2:CH13="",Jennifer!A1,)},
    Groups!C2:C),
  Groups!C1,)
)&CHAR(10)&
ArrayFormula(
  IF(REGEXMATCH(
    Groups!D2:D,
    {IF(Dalene!B2:CH13="",Dalene!A1&"|",)&
    IF(Rachel!B2:CH13="",Rachel!A1&"|",)&
    IF(Phillip!B2:CH13="",Phillip!A1&"|",)&
    IF(Jay!B2:CH13="",Jay!A1&"|",)&
    IF(Jameson!B2:CH13="",Jameson!A1&"|",)&
    IF('Scott E'!B2:CH13="",'Scott E'!A1&"|",)&
    IF(Chuck!B2:CH13="",Chuck!A1&"|",)&
    IF(Jennifer!B2:CH13="",Jennifer!A1,)}),
  Groups!D1,)
))
```

How the sheet works is each member has their own tab to mark when they are available (clear box means "available", "x" means "busy")

If they are available, their name is added to the corresponding cell in "Availability" which is then `|` delimited.

---

**EDIT:**

Once all of the calendar cells are populated with the names of those available, that list of names is then compared to each band list from the "Bands" tab.  If a combination of names matches *all* of the names in any of the columns, the band name(s) (header) above those columns is displayed in the cell (not the individuals names).

*** Changed "Groups" to "Bands" ***

---

I hope I've explained everything...

Here is my sheet.  Thank you so much for any assistance!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jE8BPrqAgQEfdCrHiFHtrMGPrD8cW-GHFyhAVYfFSrk/edit?usp=sharing

**UPDATE:**

This formula, albeit clunky, does what I'm wanting.  I'm sure there is bound to be a much simpler method, but this is what I was able to come up and only have to enter the code a single time without dragging.

```excel
=ArrayFormula(
  IF(IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Dalene!$B$2:$CQ="",Dalene!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$C$2:$C)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Rachel!$B$2:$CQ="",Rachel!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$C$2:$C)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Phillip!$B$2:$CQ="",Phillip!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$C$2:$C)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jay!$B$2:$CQ="",Jay!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$C$2:$C)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jameson!$B$2:$CQ="",Jameson!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$C$2:$C)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF('Scott E'!$B$2:$CQ="",'Scott E'!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$C$2:$C)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Chuck!$B$2:$CQ="",Chuck!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$C$2:$C)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jennifer!$B$2:$CQ="",Jennifer!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$C$2:$C)),1,)
 =COUNTA(Bands!$C$2:$C),Bands!$C$1&CHAR(10),)&

  IF(IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Dalene!$B$2:$CQ="",Dalene!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$D$2:$D)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Rachel!$B$2:$CQ="",Rachel!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$D$2:$D)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Phillip!$B$2:$CQ="",Phillip!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$D$2:$D)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jay!$B$2:$CQ="",Jay!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$D$2:$D)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jameson!$B$2:$CQ="",Jameson!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$D$2:$D)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF('Scott E'!$B$2:$CQ="",'Scott E'!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$D$2:$D)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Chuck!$B$2:$CQ="",Chuck!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$D$2:$D)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jennifer!$B$2:$CQ="",Jennifer!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$D$2:$D)),1,)
 =COUNTA(Bands!$D$2:$D),Bands!$D$1&CHAR(10),)&

  IF(IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Dalene!$B$2:$CQ="",Dalene!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$E$2:$E)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Rachel!$B$2:$CQ="",Rachel!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$E$2:$E)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Phillip!$B$2:$CQ="",Phillip!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$E$2:$E)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jay!$B$2:$CQ="",Jay!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$E$2:$E)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jameson!$B$2:$CQ="",Jameson!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$E$2:$E)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF('Scott E'!$B$2:$CQ="",'Scott E'!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$E$2:$E)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Chuck!$B$2:$CQ="",Chuck!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$E$2:$E)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jennifer!$B$2:$CQ="",Jennifer!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$E$2:$E)),1,)
 =COUNTA(Bands!$E$2:$E),Bands!$E$1&CHAR(10),)&

  IF(IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Dalene!$B$2:$CQ="",Dalene!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$F$2:$F)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Rachel!$B$2:$CQ="",Rachel!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$F$2:$F)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Phillip!$B$2:$CQ="",Phillip!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$F$2:$F)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jay!$B$2:$CQ="",Jay!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$F$2:$F)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jameson!$B$2:$CQ="",Jameson!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$F$2:$F)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF('Scott E'!$B$2:$CQ="",'Scott E'!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$F$2:$F)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Chuck!$B$2:$CQ="",Chuck!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$F$2:$F)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jennifer!$B$2:$CQ="",Jennifer!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$F$2:$F)),1,)
 =COUNTA(Bands!$F$2:$F),Bands!$F$1&CHAR(10),)&

  IF(IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Dalene!$B$2:$CQ="",Dalene!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$G$2:$G)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Rachel!$B$2:$CQ="",Rachel!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$G$2:$G)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Phillip!$B$2:$CQ="",Phillip!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$G$2:$G)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jay!$B$2:$CQ="",Jay!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$G$2:$G)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jameson!$B$2:$CQ="",Jameson!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$G$2:$G)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF('Scott E'!$B$2:$CQ="",'Scott E'!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$G$2:$G)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Chuck!$B$2:$CQ="",Chuck!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$G$2:$G)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jennifer!$B$2:$CQ="",Jennifer!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$G$2:$G)),1,)
 =COUNTA(Bands!$G$2:$G),Bands!$G$1&CHAR(10),)&

  IF(IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Dalene!$B$2:$CQ="",Dalene!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$H$2:$H)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Rachel!$B$2:$CQ="",Rachel!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$H$2:$H)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Phillip!$B$2:$CQ="",Phillip!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$H$2:$H)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jay!$B$2:$CQ="",Jay!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$H$2:$H)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jameson!$B$2:$CQ="",Jameson!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$H$2:$H)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF('Scott E'!$B$2:$CQ="",'Scott E'!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$H$2:$H)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Chuck!$B$2:$CQ="",Chuck!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$H$2:$H)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jennifer!$B$2:$CQ="",Jennifer!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$H$2:$H)),1,)
 =COUNTA(Bands!$H$2:$H),Bands!$H$1&CHAR(10),)&

  IF(IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Dalene!$B$2:$CQ="",Dalene!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$I$2:$I)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Rachel!$B$2:$CQ="",Rachel!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$I$2:$I)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Phillip!$B$2:$CQ="",Phillip!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$I$2:$I)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jay!$B$2:$CQ="",Jay!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$I$2:$I)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jameson!$B$2:$CQ="",Jameson!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$I$2:$I)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF('Scott E'!$B$2:$CQ="",'Scott E'!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$I$2:$I)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Chuck!$B$2:$CQ="",Chuck!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$I$2:$I)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jennifer!$B$2:$CQ="",Jennifer!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$I$2:$I)),1,)
 =COUNTA(Bands!$I$2:$I),Bands!$I$1&CHAR(10),)&

  IF(IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Dalene!$B$2:$CQ="",Dalene!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$J$2:$J)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Rachel!$B$2:$CQ="",Rachel!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$J$2:$J)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Phillip!$B$2:$CQ="",Phillip!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$J$2:$J)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jay!$B$2:$CQ="",Jay!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$J$2:$J)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jameson!$B$2:$CQ="",Jameson!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$J$2:$J)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF('Scott E'!$B$2:$CQ="",'Scott E'!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$J$2:$J)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Chuck!$B$2:$CQ="",Chuck!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$J$2:$J)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jennifer!$B$2:$CQ="",Jennifer!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$J$2:$J)),1,)
 =COUNTA(Bands!$J$2:$J),Bands!$J$1&CHAR(10),)&

  IF(IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Dalene!$B$2:$CQ="",Dalene!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$K$2:$K)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Rachel!$B$2:$CQ="",Rachel!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$K$2:$K)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Phillip!$B$2:$CQ="",Phillip!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$K$2:$K)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jay!$B$2:$CQ="",Jay!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$K$2:$K)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jameson!$B$2:$CQ="",Jameson!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$K$2:$K)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF('Scott E'!$B$2:$CQ="",'Scott E'!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$K$2:$K)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Chuck!$B$2:$CQ="",Chuck!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$K$2:$K)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jennifer!$B$2:$CQ="",Jennifer!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$K$2:$K)),1,)
 =COUNTA(Bands!$K$2:$K),Bands!$K$1&CHAR(10),)&

  IF(IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Dalene!$B$2:$CQ="",Dalene!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$L$2:$L)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Rachel!$B$2:$CQ="",Rachel!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$L$2:$L)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Phillip!$B$2:$CQ="",Phillip!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$L$2:$L)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jay!$B$2:$CQ="",Jay!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$L$2:$L)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jameson!$B$2:$CQ="",Jameson!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$L$2:$L)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF('Scott E'!$B$2:$CQ="",'Scott E'!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$L$2:$L)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Chuck!$B$2:$CQ="",Chuck!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$L$2:$L)),1,)+
  IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(Jennifer!$B$2:$CQ="",Jennifer!$A$1&CHAR(10),),TEXTJOIN("|",1,Bands!$L$2:$L)),1,)
 =COUNTA(Bands!$L$2:$L),Bands!$L$1&CHAR(10),)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear on the group portion of your question, but this will get everyone in one cell, and then can be a lookup or something similar to get the group name.

If you replace the 'x' in each person's calendar with a checkbox, then you can use the following formula in the overview tab:

```
 =TEXTJOIN(", ", True, 
  IF(Person1!B2, "", "Person1"), 
  IF(Person2!B2, "", "Person2")
)
```

[View sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hu1VSUzZFlGCyZzcPKJCC7H34MXfiJhSFRbJ0dZeHuU/edit?usp=sharing)

### Explanation

A checkmark is viewed by the sheets as either true or false.  So I ask if the cell checked (true), then show nothing, if it is blank (False), then show the persons name.  The TEXTJOIN aggregates all of the IF statements into one cell.

Add additional IF statements for each additional person, and then add the formula to each cell. You can change the delimitator to anything you want in the TEXTJOIN formula.

### Update

Here is how to do it with an array formula at the top and get the group name into the cell.  This isn't a dynamic solution, you would have to maintain the formula to account for new groups:

```
=ArrayFormula(
  REGEXREPLACE(
    ( IF((Person1!B2:B11=False)*(Person2!B2:B11=false), "Group1", "")
      &", "& IF((Person2!B2:B11=False)*(Person3!B2:B11=false), "Group2", "")
      &", "& IF((Person1!B2:B11=False)*(Person3!B2:B11=false)*(Person3!B2:B11=false), "Group3", "")
    ), 
 "^[, ]+|[, ]+$|(, )+","$1")
)
```

Comment: I updated the description to hopefully give a better understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish.  Thank you very much for looking at it!